# Running a job even if app is closed (Android Oreo)

Tags: java, android, service, background-task

Helo,

I've upgraded my app to Android 8.0 and higher. But now my background pushup notifications doesn't work.

My app worked great, when I used a service with a timer. So my database of pushup notifications was reloaded every 4 minutes.

Now in Android 8.0 everything seems broken. There is an Exception, when I run an app and it is forced to close.

So, now I tried this library: https://evernote.github.io/android-job/ . I created a periodical job. But when I close the app, the job is gone.

My question is:

- How can I do background task, even if the app is closed, in Android 8.0 and higher? Maybe somone could write me an example or link a website, which handles this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) imposes limitations on what apps can do
>   while running in the background.

In this case:

> When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several
>   minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At
>   the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this
>   time, **the system stops the app's background services**, just as if the
>   app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods.

Use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)

In this case the docs suggest that *your app can replace background services with [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) jobs*.

Comment: Somebody knows, if there is an example or tutorial on the web?

Comment: Actually get introduced to the limitations here https://youtu.be/Pumf_4yjTMc and after read the docs